# How to Trigger a Modal with a Link

Tags: html, url, next.js, modal-dialog, popup

I have a modal on my page (Next.js) that is triggered clicking a button:

```
<button type='button' onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
```

The modal:

```
<Modal
  id='demo'
  show={isOpen}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
>
```

The modal is hidden by default. And I would like to send a link to client. When the client clicks on the link, they will be brought to the page with the modal opened. Is it possible to do this? How? Thank you very much.

I tried to put the id in the URL like: https://example.com/contact#demo , but no luck. I was thinking about using the query mark(?), but can't figure how it would work.

Comment: aure you using nextjs with react-dom ?

Comment: You could pass a query parameter like `/contact?demo=true` or something and open the modal via js if it's present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if NextJS is with react-dom then you can use `useSearchParams` from `react-router-dom`

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'
...
....
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const q = searchParams.get('demo')

  return (
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, based on your answer, I used 'useSearchParams' from 'next/navigation' with useEffect to do it.
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

Answer (score 0):

you could detect the `referrer` which tells you from which link the client was navigated to your page. you can define `getServerSideProps`

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  let referred=false
  //  headers: IncomingHttpHeaders;
  // IncomingHttpHeaders has 'referer'?: string;
  const referrer=context.req.headers.referer
  if (referrer===YOURlINK){
       referred=true
  }
  return { props: {referred:referred} };
};
```

then based on `referred` prop

```
const referred=props.referred
<Modal
  id='demo'
  // if referred is true, it will show if referred is false, it will look isOpen value
  show={referred || isOpen}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
>
```

---

You could handle this  in client side as well

```
const [referred,setReferred]=useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    const referrer = document.referrer;
    if (referrer !== null) {
      console.log(`I was redirected from ${referrer}`);
    }
   if (referrer===YOURlINK){
       setReferred(true)
   }
  }, []);
```

using `referred` state value

```
<Modal
  id='demo'
  show={referred || isOpen}
  onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
>
```